# Canvas: Trying to draw too large bitmap. How do I fix this?

Tags: javascript, java, android, android-layout, android-studio

I have an app that throws an error whenever I try to run the app on larger screen (With android studio emulator) It only does it on the screens with larger resolution though.

The background image that I am using in the app is set its size to twice the size of the screen, could this be the problem?

I have made it so the background rotates (for aesthetic purposes) I have set it to be twice the size of the screen as that is the only way I could figure out how to make it so that when the image rotates it does not leave parts of the screen without a background on it.

Whenever I try to run my app it throws this error:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>
> Process: com.learn.earn.earnlearnapp, PID: 3039
>
> java.lang.RuntimeException: Canvas: trying to draw too large(294000000bytes) bitmap.